# Synchronizer with approximate time policy in a class [C++]

Tags: ros, c++, ros-kinetic, message-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to implement a synchronizer with approximate time policy in a class. The following code compiles with no problem. But how should I define the `Synchronizer` and the `registerCallback`? (The two commented lines)

```
#include "header.h"
using namespace message_filters;
typedef control_sys::IntWithHeader myMsg;

class Node
{
    
public:

    Node()
{
    sub1.subscribe(node, "in1", 1);
    sub2.subscribe(node, "in2", 1);
    
}
    void callback(const myMsg &in1, const myMsg &in2)
{
        std::cout << "Synchronization successful" << std::endl;
}   
    
 
private:

    ros::NodeHandle node;
    ros::Publisher pub;
    std_msgs::Int32 out;
    message_filters::Subscriber<myMsg> sub1;
    message_filters::Subscriber<myMsg> sub2;
    typedef sync_policies::ApproximateTime<myMsg, myMsg> MySyncPolicy;
    // This is how I would define them inside main()
    //Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> sync(MySyncPolicy(10), sub1, sub2);
    //sync.registerCallback(&callback);
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    ros::init(argc, argv, "synchronizer");
    Node synchronizer;

    ros::spin();

}
```

**Update 1:** Headers included:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int32.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/synchronizer.h>
#include <message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h>
#include "control_sys/IntWithHeader.h"
```

**Update 2:** [Error output of `catkin_make`](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mgi1118e83tfkal/log.txt?dl=0) (in terminal)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280856/synchronizer-with-approximate-time-policy-in-a-class-%5Bc++%5D/) by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 249 on 2018-01-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2018-01-25**:
What are the includes in `header.h`?

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2018-01-26**:
One of the errors is `/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:299:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Node*’ to ‘Node&’`. Can you put an update showing the file as you have it now? That looks suspicious, like a copy-paste error from one of us.

**Comment by [Vince4396](https://answers.ros.org/users/36767/vince4396/) on 2018-07-31**:
I am wondering if your final code is working. I have been trying to implement a similar class as yours but my callback function is never called.

**Comment by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) on 2018-08-02**:
I haven't run this for a while, but I remember that it was working fine. [Have a look](https://github.com/mohse-n/src/blob/master/control_sys/src/angle_cont.cpp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Change your commented out lines to:

```
typedef sync_policies::ApproximateTime<myMsg, myMsg> MySyncPolicy;
typedef Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> Sync;
boost::shared_ptr<Sync> sync;
```

In your constructor initialize and register:

```
sync.reset(new Sync(MySyncPolicy(10), sub1, sub2));      
sync->registerCallback(boost::bind(&Node::callback, this, _1, _2));
```

**Update**

A couple of other things to keep in mind.

1. The messages you are subscribing to *require* a `std_msgs/Header` field so that message times can be compared.
2. Change the signature of your callback to `void callback(const control_sys::IntWithHeaderConstPtr &in1, const control_sys::IntWithHeaderConstPtr &in2)`.

With those types of changes I was able to get a node to compile that basically mimics what you have. I had to substitue `myMsg` for `sensor_msgs/Image` in order to use a message type I have access to.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2018-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) on 2018-01-25**:
sync->registerCallback(boost::bind(&Node::callback, this, _1, _2));

The line above causes a wall of error when I compile the package. It's too long to paste but I hope this helps.

```
error: no match for call to ‘(boost::_mfi::mf2<void, Node,
```

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2018-01-25**:
That is probably because you have not declared your callback function. After the parts that were commented out try `void callback(const myMsg &in1, const myMsg &in2);`

**Comment by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) on 2018-01-25**:
It still gives the same error (boost) + new errors caused by (I think) illegal function overload.

```
 error: ‘void Node::callback(const myMsg&, const myMsg&)’ cannot be overloaded  

 error: with ‘void Node::callback(const myMsg&, const myMsg&)’
```

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2018-01-25**:
Try making the function definition `private`.

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2018-01-25**:
Looking at it more, I think I was wrong about needing the extra function declaration in the code as you have it. Sorry about that.

**Comment by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) on 2018-01-26**:
That's alright. This is pretty advanced C++ for me so I really appreciate your help. Making the definition `private` didn't make a difference.

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2018-01-26**:
I have a gist of the entire package that builds for me at https://gist.github.com/tdenewiler/e2172f628e49ab633ef2786207793336.

**Comment by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) on 2018-01-27**:
Thanks for the update. But `myMsgConstPtr` is not a valid type so instead I changed the callback to

```
void callback(const control_sys::IntWithHeaderConstPtr &in1, const control_sys::IntWithHeaderConstPtr &in2)
```

and now it compiles and works properly. Would you mind editing your answer?

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2018-01-27**:
To use `myMsgConstPtr` you would have to add `typedef control_sys::IntWithHeaderConstPtr myMsgConstPtr;`.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What follows is a correct version of the code:

```
#include "header.h"
using namespace message_filters;
typedef control_sys::IntWithHeader myMsg;

class Node
{
    
public:

    Node()
{
    sub1.subscribe(node, "in1", 1);
    sub2.subscribe(node, "in2", 1);
    sync.reset(new Sync(MySyncPolicy(10), sub1, sub2));   
    sync->registerCallback(boost::bind(&Node::callback, this, _1, _2));

     
}

    void callback(const control_sys::IntWithHeaderConstPtr &in1, const control_sys::IntWithHeaderConstPtr &in2)
{
         std::cout << "Synchronization successful" << std::endl;
}  

private:

    ros::NodeHandle node;
    ros::Publisher pub;
    std_msgs::Int32 out;

    message_filters::Subscriber<myMsg> sub1;
    message_filters::Subscriber<myMsg> sub2;
    typedef sync_policies::ApproximateTime<myMsg, myMsg> MySyncPolicy;
    typedef Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> Sync;
    boost::shared_ptr<Sync> sync;
    
};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    ros::init(argc, argv, "synchronizer");

    Node synchronizer;

    ros::spin();

}
```

---

Originally posted by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) with karma: 249 on 2018-01-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-27**:
Is this your solution or an update to your question?

**Comment by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) on 2018-01-28**:
The solution.

**Comment by [thorper](https://answers.ros.org/users/25668/thorper/) on 2018-09-07**:
This helped me!

**Comment by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) on 2018-09-10**:
Glad to hear that!

**Comment by [apletta](https://answers.ros.org/users/43189/apletta/) on 2019-07-03**:
This really helped me too!

**Comment by [CoffeeKangaroo](https://answers.ros.org/users/34027/coffeekangaroo/) on 2023-03-23**:
This should be marked as accepted answer.